Можно ли для диска увеличить память в Linux mint?
Когда я устанавливал Linux Mint я делал ручную установку из видео-инструкции.
У меня SSD 245GB и я его разделил на два тома один для Windows 11, другой для Linux Mint (32GB). Теперь у меня не хватает места, можно ли как-то без переустановки, увеличить объем с другого тома.

ДОПОЛНЕНО:




Не хватает места где? Почему томов на скриншоте не два, а семь? Почему между четвёртым и пятым неиспользуемое место? Что-то странное вы намудрили

Но если про всё остальное ещё можно более-менее догадаться, то смысл существования самого последнего раздела — загадка. Если вы наслушались глупостей про отдельный раздел /home, то зря вы их наслушались

@andreymal между четвертым и пятым я убрал расширив четвертый том. Первый том для режима восстановления на Windows 2 и 3 я не знаю для чего используются. А про  глупостей про отдельный раздел /home я не знаю. Мне просто нужно как-то увеличить объем памяти на томе с Linux Mint. Вы знаете как это можно сделать ?

Какой из томов — том с Linux Mint? Если пятый, то для чего ещё вам тогда седьмой?

@andreymal посмотрите на обновленные скриншоты, а седьмой это для /home похоже.

Эх, всё-таки отдельный раздел /home, ну страдайте теперь. // «расширив четвертый том» — ужмите обратно, вам же теперь раздел с Linux Mint увеличивать некуда

А если в Linux Mint ещё успело появиться ничего ценного, я бы рекомендовал снести разделы 5-6-7 к чертям, всесто них создать одной большой раздел и установить Linux Mint уже на него — меньше страдать будете, делить такой маленький объём на разделы не очень разумно

@andreymal я просто установил Linux Mint для теста, а потом не заметил как пересел на неё. Т.е без сохранения данных не увеличить объём, только переустановка?

Ну если вы ужмёте раздел 4 обратно, то сможете через live-образ с флешки расширить раздел 5 в то самое ужатое место. Только вот потом однажды на разделе 7 тоже кончится место, а с ним вы уже ничего не сделаете и в итоге будете страдать

Без переустановки можно помудрить вот так: 1) в файле etc/fstab на разделе 5 отключить home и подкачку; 2) удалить подкачку (раздел 6); 3) расширить раздел 5 на место удалённого раздела подкачки; 4) Переместить файлы из раздела 7 в каталог home на разделе 5; 5) удалить раздел 7; 6) расширить раздел 5 на место удалённого раздела 7. Все действия проводить строго через live-систему (то есть загрузиться с флешки) и важно не перепутать файлы на разделе 5 с файлами на live-системе

Расширенные действия с разделами возможны, в частности, разделение и слияние существующих разделов без удаления данных.
Вот первый попавшийся гайд:
https://remontka.pro/merge-disk-partitions/
